# how to install VC2012 using winetricks in Ubuntu

Tags: winetricks

```
$ winetricks --force

Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.

Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.

Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.

Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.

Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.

Executing w_do_call vcrun2012

Executing load_vcrun2012

Using native,builtin override for following DLLs: atl110 msvcp110 msvcr110 vcomp110

Executing winetricks_early_wine regedit /S C:\windows\Temp\_vcrun2012\override-dll.reg

Executing wine vcredist_x86.exe /q

err:ole:CoInitializeEx Attempt to change threading model of this apartment from multi-threaded to apartment threaded

err:ole:CoInitializeEx Attempt to change threading model of this apartment from multi-threaded to apartment threaded

------------------------------------------------------

Note: command 'wine vcredist_x86.exe /q' returned status 180.  Aborting.

------------------------------------------------------

Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
```

Answer (score 0):

[WineHQ database entry for Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Package](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=5766)

Anything below Gold is a waste of time: It may or may not install and even if installed it won't work.

Bottom line: Don't waste your time.

Comment: to think most of the games released these days requires vc2015...

Comment: Actually many games released this days at Steam and other platforms are either native, "native" (ported) or "Wine-wrapped" so you don't need to install Wine and/or additional Windows components. Specifically re: your question, I suggest reading the whole page, clicking the links and read the tests and comments. BTW, this is the correct answer and there's no other ATM (it could change anytime) so consider accepting it.

Comment: Games like Blade And Soul, Rusty Hearts and many other mmorpgs are not thou...

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.